# How to connect two laptops and a pc to each other?

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop, lan

I want to connect two laptops with wireless and connect them to a computer with lan cable for playing. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a wireless network from one laptop and bridge it to the ethernet port on the same laptop. Use a [crossover cable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable) or get a crossover adapter for a regular ethernet cable to connect that laptop to the pc. Have the remaining laptop connect to the other laptop's wifi.

Answer (score 3):

It's probably easiest to buy a router and connect all of them with cable (or some of them using wireless network). As far as I know, you need to have some kind of switch or router.

Comment: I think there is another way ... without routers.

Comment: A router would be the easiest solution.

Answer (score 1):

Using a switch or a router should solve the case

Comment: no. my pc doesn't have wireless and i don't have a switch or a router